# Generating apk with explicit ids for elements

Tags: android, android-studio, maps

In my application I am used the Google Maps API, and I use a hack to be able repositionar the zoom buttons and MyLocation

```
   View zoomControls = (View) getView().findViewById(0x1);
   View myLocation =   (View) getView().findViewById(0x2);
```

Before I update the android gradle the studio was generating the apk normally now when I try to generate the apk it gives the following message
Error: Error: Expected resource of type id [ResourceType]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way for get the view for my location button without errors is:

```
View myLocation =  (View) mapFragment.getView().findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the ids in ids.xml with

```
 <resources>
        <item type="id" name="zoomcontrol" />
        <item type="id" name="myLocation " />
    </resources>
```

And use them in code like R.id.*

```
View zoomControls = (View) getView().findViewById(R.id.zoomcontrol);
View myLocation =   (View) getView().findViewById(R.id.myLocation );
```

Comment: this does not work, man ... Because the names of these ids believe it is not that.